# Copy found emails 4 times

Tags: vba, outlook

I have macro that searches for a subject and if found copy the email in another folder. My problem is that it copies the email 4 times instead of only once. If i have 10 emails in the original folder "Left Ones" then, after search and copy  i will have 40 emails in the folder "TO BE REMOVED" . Any help is welcomed, thank you.

```
Sub Search_Inbox()

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim filteredItems As Outlook.Items
Dim itm As Object
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim strFilter As String
Dim subject_to_find As String
Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder

subject_to_find = "something"

Set objNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = OpenOutlookFolder("\\Mailbox - ME\Inbox\Left Ones")

strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & subject_to_find & "%'"

Set filteredItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)

If filteredItems.Count = 0 Then

    Debug.Print "No emails found"
    Found = False

Else
    Found = True

    For Each itm In filteredItems
    If itm.Class = olMail Then
    Debug.Print itm.Subject
    Debug.Print itm.ReceivedTime
    End If

  Set myDestFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - ME").Folders("TO BE REMOVED")

    For i = filteredItems.Count To 1 Step -1
            Dim myCopiedItem As Object

            Set myCopiedItem = filteredItems(i).Copy
            myCopiedItem.Move myDestFolder

    Next i

    Next itm

End If

'If the subject isn't found:
If Not Found Then
    'NoResults.Show
Else
   Debug.Print "Found " & filteredItems.Count & " items."
End If

Set myOlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Wild guess: copying & moving items messes up `filteredItems`. Try: (1) in your loop: add the items to a collection, (2) run copy&move on the collection items.

Comment: Debug the code with F8. When you know what the outer loop does move whatever you want from the outer loop into the inner loop then remove the outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
Else
    Found = True
```

add the line

```
Debug.Print filteredItems.Count
```

This is to check the number of items found. This way, you can definitely see if VBA actually finds 40 emails (for whatever reason), or if it just copies it 4 times later on.

Also try Changing

```
Next i
```

to

```
i = i + 1
```

Edit:

Cut the

```
Next itm
```

and move it to the end of this block:

```
For Each itm In filteredItems
    If itm.Class = olMail Then
      Debug.Print itm.Subject
      Debug.Print itm.ReceivedTime
    End If
Next itm 'move it here
```

Comment: Hi, it finds the correct number but i must decrease not increase and i have tried i=i-1 but is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers here is the working code to find all the emails with a given subject in a subfolder - Inbox\Left Ones - and copy them in another subfolder - Inbox\TO BE REMOVED - ( note that it will leave out the undelivered notification ) :

```
        Sub Search_Inbox_Subfolder_Left_Ones()

        Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim filteredItems As Outlook.Items
        Dim itm As Object
        Dim Found As Boolean
        Dim strFilter As String
        Dim subject_to_find As String
        Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Dim myCopiedItem As Object

        subject_to_find = "something to find"

        Set objFolder = OpenOutlookFolder("\\Mailbox - ME\Inbox\Left Ones")

        strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & subject_to_find & "%'"

        Set filteredItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)

        If filteredItems.Count = 0 Then

            Debug.Print "No emails found"
            Found = False

        Else
            Found = True

     Set myDestFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - ME").Folders("TO BE REMOVED")

            For i = filteredItems.Count To 1 Step -1

             If filteredItems(i).Class = olMail Then

                    Set myCopiedItem = filteredItems(i).Copy
                    myCopiedItem.Move myDestFolder

             End If

            Next i

        End If

        'If the subject isn't found:
        If Not Found Then
            'NoResults.Show
        Else
           Debug.Print "Found " & filteredItems.Count & " items."
        End If

        Set myOlApp = Nothing

        End Sub

Private Function OpenOutlookFolder(strFolderPath As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim arrFolders As Variant, _
        varFolder As Variant, _
        bolBeyondRoot As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    If strFolderPath = "" Then
        Set OpenOutlookFolder = Nothing
    Else
        Do While Left(strFolderPath, 1) = "\"
            strFolderPath = Right(strFolderPath, Len(strFolderPath) - 1)
        Loop
        arrFolders = Split(strFolderPath, "\")
        For Each varFolder In arrFolders
            Select Case bolBeyondRoot
                Case False
                    Set OpenOutlookFolder = Outlook.Session.Folders(varFolder)
                    bolBeyondRoot = True
                Case True
                    Set OpenOutlookFolder = OpenOutlookFolder.Folders(varFolder)
            End Select
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Set OpenOutlookFolder = Nothing
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```